# (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))

Tags: python, macos, x86, importerror, apple-silicon

I have a problem when I run a .py file on a Macbook Air M1:

```
[Running] python3 -u "/Users/kaiyuwei/Documents/graduation project/metaheuristics/run_CRO.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kaiyuwei/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/Users/kaiyuwei/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "/Users/kaiyuwei/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 6, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/kaiyuwei/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-38-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/kaiyuwei/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-38-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kaiyuwei/Documents/graduation project/metaheuristics/run_CRO.py", line 1, in <module>
    from models.multiple_solution.evolutionary_based.CRO import BaseCRO
  File "/Users/kaiyuwei/Documents/graduation project/metaheuristics/models/multiple_solution/evolutionary_based/CRO.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/Users/kaiyuwei/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/Users/kaiyuwei/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.8 from "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.23.1"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: dlopen(/Users/kaiyuwei/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-38-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/kaiyuwei/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-38-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))


[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.055 seconds
```

I think the reason is that I'm using the `numpy` package for 'x86_64', so I tried to use `pip install numpy --upgrade` to upgrade numpy, but I got output like:

```
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /Users/kaiyuwei/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (1.23.1)
```

I also tried `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` to upgrade python, but still;

```
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /Users/kaiyuwei/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (22.1.2)
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solved the problem by simply uninstalling numpy package:

```
pip3 uninstall numpy
```

and reinstalling it:

```
pip3 install numpy
```

Comment: what does `file` command say about that shared object now? does it support both architectures

Comment: This does not help. This is more of an architecture issue.

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me -

```
ARCHFLAGS="-arch arm64" pip install numpy  --compile --no-cache-dir
```

Answer (score 7):

For my Mac M1 processor best variant of installation is the command

```
pip3 install numpy==1.24.0  --compile --force-reinstall
```

Comment: Great solution. It solved my issue with `pydantic` on my M1 Max.

Comment: Oh, the ``--compile`` prefix successfully installs absolutely all modules for OSX.

Comment: Same situation about ``PyObjC`` which was incompatible to my OSX version.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue in pycharm executing tests.

The problem was the **interpreter** for the test case was set to the **wrong** one.

Going to **edit configurations** for the test case fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and after uninstalling and reinstalling didn't work, I updated to Python 3.11 and it works perfectly now.