# While importing the Tensorflow. Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tkinter, import

I've got a error mesage when I am trying to install tensorflow to my project.

It's a little bit long traceback but I'm sure there are some heroes right there to help me tackle with that.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import filedialog
import numpy as np
import tensorflow
from tensorflow.keras.applications import vgg16
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import decode_predictions
```

> 

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 0x0006): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (x86_64), need (arm64e)))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/volfcan/Documents/Coding/Python/Python/Tkinter/Image Classifier w: Tkinter/image_classifier_tkinter.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorflow
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 0x0006): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (x86_64), need (arm64e)))


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Thank you for your interest in making the world forward.

I am trying to to deploy a machine learning image classifier project with tkinter module on python.

Comment: The error is self-explanatory:  (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (x86_64), need (arm64e))) You installed TensorFlow for Intel but you have an ARM processor.

Answer (score 0):

As answered in: [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72920835/13954475)

You can try uninstalling numpy package:

```
pip3 uninstall numpy
```

and reinstalling it:

```
pip3 install numpy
```

Comment: I tried it but still got the same error.

I just updated the import section on the question. Any chance it is related to importing TensorFlow line? How the uninstalling the NumPy module related to it?

Comment: This may be related to the installation of your tensorflow with the architecture. Take a look at this link:
[link](https://developer.codeplay.com/products/computecpp/ce/1.1.6/guides/tensorflow-guide/tensorflow-arm-setup)